# Pandas: Remove index entry (and all it's rows) from multilevel index when all data in a column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to clean up some data I have in a dataframe with a multilevel index.

```
                | A   | B   | 
----------------+-----+-----+
foo  2019-01-01 | x   | NaN |
     2019-01-02 | x   | NaN |
     2019-01-03 | NaN | NaN |
................+.....+.....+
bar  2019-01-01 | NaN | x   |
     2019-01-02 | NaN | y   |
     2019-01-03 | NaN | z   |
................+.....+.....+
baz  2019-01-01 | x   | x   |
     2019-01-02 | x   | x   |
     2019-01-03 | x   | x   |
```

I'd like to loose the complete group indexed by **bar**, because all of the data in column **A** is *NaN*. I'd like to keep **foo**, because only some of the data in column **A** is *NaN* (column **B** is not important here, even if it's all *NaN*). I'd like to keep **baz**, because not all of column **A**is *NaN*.
So my result should look like this:

```
                | A   | B   | 
----------------+-----+-----+
foo  2019-01-01 | x   | NaN |
     2019-01-02 | x   | NaN |
     2019-01-03 | NaN | NaN |
................+.....+.....+
baz  2019-01-01 | x   | x   |
     2019-01-02 | x   | x   |
     2019-01-03 | x   | x   |
```

What's the best way to do this with pandas and python? I suppose there is a better way than looping through the data...

Comment: `s=df.groupby(level=0).A.transform(lambda x: x.isna().all())` and then `df=df[~s]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), [`notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) & [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html)

We can `groupby` on your first level index and then check if *any* of the values in column A are not `NaN`.

We use `transform` to get the same shaped boolean array back so we can use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) to filter out the correct rows.

```
m = df['A'].notna().groupby(level=0).transform('any')
df[m]
```

```
                  A    B
idx idx2                
foo 2019-01-01    x  NaN
    2019-01-02    x  NaN
    2019-01-03  NaN  NaN
baz 2019-01-01    x    x
    2019-01-02    x    x
    2019-01-03    x    x
```

---

What does `m` return?

```
m = df['A'].notna().groupby(level=0).transform('any')
print(m)

idx  idx2      
foo  2019-01-01     True
     2019-01-02     True
     2019-01-03     True
bar  2019-01-01    False
     2019-01-02    False
     2019-01-03    False
baz  2019-01-01     True
     2019-01-02     True
     2019-01-03     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Solid solution. However there can be a large performance drop for larger frames with many groups due to the `lambda`. It's often better to check the `notnull` on the whole `DataFrame` then groupby with just `any`: `m = df.A.notnull().groupby(level=0).transform('any')`

Comment: Good point thanks, was actually looking for a method not using `lambda`. Edited accordingly. Btw its best practice to not use `notnull` or `isnull` and instead use `notna` and `isna` since they are in line with `fillna, dropna`. @ALollz

Comment: @Efran I could be wrong, but I believe they are simple aliases for each other. See the "See also" of https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notnull.html

Comment: Yes thats true, but I read a post of one of pandas developers that they want to allign these and in the future get rid isnull and notnull (cant find the post, if I find it, will link it here) @ALollz

Comment: I think you are referring to something along the lines of this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18262#issuecomment-346504304, though the sentiment I get from that is it's not going anywhere. Then again, that was 2 years ago, so maybe it's changed.