# Group values together in Pandas column, then filter values in another column

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Pandas Dataframe looks like so:

```
Col1 Col2

A    1
A    1
A    1
B    0
B    0
B    1
B    1
B    1
C    1
C    1
C    1
C    1
```

I wanted to group all together in `Col1`, then check `Col2` to see whether  **all** values for that group i.e. A are 1. In this example the desired output would be:

```
[A, C]
```

(because only A and C have all values set to 1). How do I do this?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869643/pandas-remove-index-entry-and-all-its-rows-from-multilevel-index-when-all-da#comment100287969_56869643).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case `groupby` with `all`

```
df.groupby('Col1').Col2.all().loc[lambda x : x ].index.tolist()
Out[350]: ['A', 'C']
```

Or without `groupby`

```
df.loc[~df.Col1.isin(df.Col1[df.Col2.eq(0)]),'Col1'].unique()
Out[352]: array(['A', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

---

From the comment

cs95 :`df.loc[df['Col2'].astype(bool).groupby(df['Col1']).transform('all'), 'Col1'].unique()`

Comment: `df.loc[df['Col2'].astype(bool).groupby(df['Col1']).transform('all'), 'Col1'].unique()`

Comment: `[*{*df.Col1[df.Col2.eq(1).groupby(df.Col1).transform(all)]}]`

Comment: @WeNYoBen: I used the first solution and it worked. I didn't try the other solutions, but I'll mark them up anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `all` with `groupby`:

```
out = df.Col2.groupby(df.Col1).all()
out.index[out].tolist()
# ['A', 'C']
```

Comment: `out.index[out]` should also be pretty clean.

Comment: Ha didnt think of putting it this way, thanks @cs95 !

Answer (score 2):

#### Comprehension

```
[k for k, d in df.Col2.eq(1).groupby(df.Col1) if d.all()]

['A', 'C']
```